# Список в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, список

Вопрос предельно прост: Как осуществить переход с конкретного элемента списка `ListView` на новое `Activity`?

Массив и Адаптер созданы, а код для перехода на `Activity` я не знаю. Вот часть существующего:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position==0){}
    // ...
}
```

Возможно нужно вставить нужный код в условии: `if(position==0){}` или можно как-то по-другому?

Comment: В Android Studio есть готовый стартовый шаблон "Master/Detail Flow" - это список с переходом на новую активити, где открывается детальная информация, соответствующая выбранному в списке айтему - изучите его и сможете сделать похожее сами.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правильно делаете. 
number - ваша позиция

```
if (position = number){
     MainActivity.this.startActivity();
}
```

Или если для каждого елемента нужно запускать нужную Activity, то лучше в классе вашего адаптера добавьте поле типа `Class<?>` и на обработчик нажатия выполняйте
ClassName - поле типа `Class<?>`

MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Items.get(position).ClassName));

Comment: Не совсем понял с полем типа Class<?> Не могли бы поподробнее, вот код:

Comment: Class<?> cls;
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, cls));